# Set Height and Width of the image using TbActiveForm

Tags: php, yii

I have the following code,

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
       'id'=>'customerform-grid',
       'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
       'filter'=>$model,
       'columns'=>array(
           'name',
            array(
                  'name'=>'logo1',
                  'header'=>'Logo',
                  'type'=>'html',
                  'value'=>'CHtml::tag("img",array("src"=>"/"."$data->logo1"))',
                  'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 50px;'),
             ),
        }
    ));
?>
```

The htmlOptions style set only table column not for image, but i want to set the height and width for the image, Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put every css style inside `style` tag of `htmlOptions` in this way:

```
'value'=>'CHtml::tag("img",array("src"=>"/"."$data->logo1", "style" => "width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 50px;"))',
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the different way you can deal with this.

Just have your desired `class` inside your code

**In PHP :**

```
array(
   'name'=>'logo1',
   'header'=>'Logo',    
   ...
   'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'SimbuClass'
    ),
)
```

And Apply your style in css

**In Css :**

```
.SimbuClass
{
   width: 50;
   height: 50;
   text-align: center;
}
```

BTW, You can re-use your class anywhere you need.